# How find the array index for two array comparision and return once array item less than another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to compare two array then return the index once first array less than second array. But if the start value of first array greater than the second array, must skip until first array value less than second array. For example

case1: This must return index = 2 (exampleArr1 < exampleArr2 at index =2)

```
   var exampleArr1 = [15,9,7,5,3,1];
   var exampleArr2 = [2,6,8,12,17,22];

  function compareArray(exampleArr1,exampleArr2){
    ...
    return result
  }
```

case2: This must return index = 6 (exampleArr1 < exampleArr2 at index =6)

```
   var exampleArr1 = [1,2,4,5,15,9,7,5,3];
   var exampleArr2 = [2,3,5,6,2,6,8,12,17];

  function compareArray(exampleArr1,exampleArr2){
    ...
    return result
  }
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: _"Any advice or guidance..."_ - You will definitely need some form of a loop.

Comment: Also JS arrays start at 0

Comment: Your second case would then return 0

Comment: Dear  mplungjan, the second need to return 6. I would like to skip in case of start first array value bigger than second array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) will suffice. In our loop, we already have the index so we just compare the first array at this index with the second array at this index.

```js
const compareArray = (arr1, arr2) => {  
  let startIndex = 0
  if (arr1[0] < arr2[0]) {
    // find the index from arr1 that is greater than arr2
    startIndex = arr1.findIndex((a, index) => a > arr2[index])
  }

  for (let i = startIndex; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[i]) {
      return i
    }
  }
}

const exampleArr1 = [15,9,7,5,3,1]
const exampleArr2 = [2,6,8,12,17,22]
const exampleArr3 = [1,2,4,5,15,9,7,5,3]
const exampleArr4 = [2,3,5,6,2,6,8,12,17]

console.log(compareArray(exampleArr1, exampleArr2))
console.log(compareArray(exampleArr3, exampleArr4))
```

Comment: Dear Cjmarkham, thanks. but compareArray(exampleArr3, exampleArr4) need to return 6. [2,3,5,6 will be skipped before comparison.

Comment: Why will they be skipped?

Comment: Dear Cjmarkham, It's a part of application. I would like to find cross signal that start with first array < second array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to suit your needs. I think the original question was worded incorrectly but I think I understood it enough.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method in your function like

```js
var exampleArr1 = [15,9,7,5,3,1];
var exampleArr2 = [2,6,8,12,17,22];

function compareArray(exampleArr1,exampleArr2) {
    if (exampleArr1[0] < exampleArr2[0]) {
        exampleArr1 = exampleArr1.slice(1);
    }
    return exampleArr1.findIndex(function(e, i) { return exampleArr2[i] > e; });
}

console.log(compareArray(exampleArr1, exampleArr2));
```

Comment: Dear uzair.ahmed, thanks.